# PyTest returns incorrect results when run dynamically

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run tests automatically when code is submitted to my Flask application, but somehow PyTest is returning the wrong results. I have tried disabling cacheing, deleting cache folders removing .pyc files but the issue remains. Here's a toy reproduction of the issue.

Directory structure:

```
app.py
right/
    main.py
    test_solution1.py
wrong/
    main.py
    test_solution2.py
```

app.py

```py
import pytest

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def submit():
    pytest.main(["right", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])
    pytest.main(["wrong", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])
    return "OK"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0")
```

right/main.py

```py
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b
```

right/test_solution1.py

```py
import main

def test_subtract():
    assert main.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

wrong/main.py

```py
def subtract(a, b):
    return b - a
```

wrong/test_solution2.py

```py
import main

def test_subtract():
    assert main.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

If I load the app and visit `localhost:5000` in my browser, it triggers the tests in each directory as expected, but both results are the same. It says all tests passed, even though the tests for `wrong` should fail.

[image: good tests]

If I swap the order that the tests are triggered in the Flask app, then the tests fail for both projects, even though they should pass for the second one.

modified submit() route for `app.py` (running the 'wrong' project first now)

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def submit():
    pytest.main(["wrong", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])
    pytest.main(["right", "-p", "no:cacheprovider"])
    return "OK"
```

Now both tests show failures, even though the 'right' project has no issues.

How can I ensure that pytest runs exactly the code in the directory? I assume it is caching the results somehow as if the `main.py` names don't clash it works fine.

Removing `__pycache__` and similar directories and files between running the tests doesn't help. Stopping and reloading the Flask server between running the tests *does* fix the issue.

Comment: having issues uploading the second screenshot showing two failures, so here it is https://i.ritzastatic.com/63d4fd298862405fa48b2eb93e4de165/errors2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in Python, if you try to import two times the same module, Python won't search in the file system the second time. It will use the module imported the first time. You are trying to import two time the module `main`. Even if you think this is two different module, from the point of view of Python you are trying to import the same module twice (because they are both named `main`). You can read more details about the [module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) system in the documentation.

Depending on what you want to do there may be many solutions. Here's two:

### Solution 1

You can simply change the name of your main module for different names:

```
app.py
right/
    main1.py
    test_solution1.py
wrong/
    main2.py
    test_solution2.py
```

**test_solution.py**

```py
import main1

def test_subtract():
    assert main1.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

**test_solution2.py**

```py
import main2

def test_subtract():
    assert main2.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

### Solution 2

You keep the same file names but you specify which submodule you want to import:

**test_solution.py**

```py
from right import main

def test_subtract():
    assert main.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

**test_solution2.py**

```py
from wrong import main

def test_subtract():
    assert main.subtract(5, 3) == 2
```

That works because Python is looking in the local directory when searching for module and you start Python at the same location where `app.py` and folders `right` and `wrong` are.